# error in LinkingSetRelation - Invalid cast ... as object

Tags: serenity-platform

I have the following error when I try to save a form with linkingsetrelation field:

Invalid cast exception while trying to set the value of ProductId field on ProductRow as object.

What can cause this error? any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

found it.... fields must be Int32, cannot use Int64!